# Excel if formula possibility

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an issue that I don't personally know how to format. I need to subtract numbers that are in seconds, formatted to be viewed as  58.43 or 59.99, but that are sometimes in minutes, formatted as 1:01.33 for example.

I would also need to be able to subtract the numbers from each other to be recognized as (+1.08) or (-0.78), with the parentheses.

I'm sure I can elaborate somewhere, so let me know if this doesn't make any sense. Thanks

Comment: When you say 'subtract the numbers', are these just normal numbers and not times?

Comment: @TomSharpe the 58.43 or 1:01.33 would be the totals of two other smaller times (ex. 28.44 +29.99 = 1:01.33). Essentially I need an if statement somewhere.

Comment: @TomSharpe I would be subtracting the two larger times from each other to find a difference.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if 58.43 is formatted as a number or time. Date and time are stored in number of days, so the time 58.43 is actually stored as the number 0.00067627314814814800000 (58.43/24/60/60).
If both values are time values, then the custom number format of the result can be:

```
(+s.00);(-s.00);(0.00);@
```

To handle both cases, instead of `=A1-A2` you can try this something like this:

```
=IF(A1<1,A1,A1/86400)-IF(A2<1,A2,A2/86400)
```

Answer (score 0):

If those are just time values formatted as mm.ss then you can use `TIMEDIFF()`

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-e1c78778-749b-49a3-b13e-737715505ff6

If not, try to convert them to time values and than use `TIMEDIFF()`

Answer (score 0):

The first part is straightforward

Apply a default format of

```
ss:00
```

Then in conditional formatting use a formula

```
=A2>=TIME(0,1,0)
```

and apply a format of

```
m:ss.00
```

for the ones that are a minute or more.

There is no direct solution to the problem of displaying negative times short of changing the default date system used by Excel as you can see in a number of references. The only way to do it here is to test whether the result is positive or negative and display the positive difference with or without a minus sign.

```
=IF(B2>=A2,TEXT(B2-A2,"(+s.00)"),TEXT(A2-B2,"(-s.00)"))
```

The downside of this is that they are actually text values and you can't use them in any further calculations. However the *results* of A2-B2 are still good even if you can't display them directly, so you can use A2-B2 in subsequent formulae if you want to even if it is negative.